# Qual é o nome do local (meta)físico onde atributos psíquicos se originam ou manifestam segundo uma cultura?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, tradução-inglês

O coração é tido popularmente como o local de onde as emoções vêm ou se manifestam. No Egito Antigo, quem cumpria este papel era o fígado. No Oriente Médio, os rins eram onde a consciência se manifestava. A alma têm função parecida, mas é de onde vêm e se manifesta a vida ou a individualidade, dependendo da cultura.

Em inglês, usa-se os termos "seat of emotion" (ver resultados [aqui¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search="seat+of+emotion") e [aqui²](https://duckduckgo.com/?q="seat+of+emotion")), "seat of will", "seat of affections", "seat of thought", etc, para referir aos locais físicos ou metafísicos onde um atributo psíquico humano se origina ou se manifesta segundo uma cultura. Como traduzir estes termos? Definir "coração" e "alma" como "berço das emoções" e "local da individualidade" me parece não ser adequado.

### Exemplos

O versículo bíblico Salm. 16:7 diz *"Bendigo a Javé que me aconselha, e, mesmo à noite, meus **rins me instruem**"*. Uma versão da Bíblia inglesa de King James comenta este versículo dizendo que "For the Semitic, the kidneys are the seat of thought", i.e., "para os semíticos, os rins são a 'sede' do pensamento".

Este parágrafo da [Wikipédia anglófona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripartite_(theology)#Old_Testament) usa estes termos para referir ao uso metafísico dos órgãos na bíblia:

> The physiology and psychology of the Hebrew and the Archaic Greek world was speculative, [...] they spoke of various physical organs as the seat of thought, feeling, and decision. The heart primarily was the seat of thought and feeling, the kidneys the seat of reflection (Psa. 16:7; 26:2; Prov. 23:6), and the bowels the seat of affection (Gen. 43:30; Phil. 1:8).
>
> > A fisiologia e psicologia do mundo Hebraico e Grego Antigo era especulativa, eles falavam de vários órgãos físicos como o "local" do pensamento, sentimento e decisão. O coração era principalmente o "local" de pensamento e emoções, os rins o "local" de reflexão (Salm. 16:7; 26:2; Prov. 23:6), e as tripas/entranhas o "local" de afeição (Gên. 43:30; Fil. 1:8).

[Este site](http://www.dtl.org/misc/treatise/soul-spirit-1.htm) diz que a alma, para os hebreus, era "the seat of passions" enquanto que o espírito era "the seat of emotions".

[Este site](http://www.houseofdavid.ca/body_metaphors_bib_hebrew.htm) possui uma grande tabela listando os trechos da bíblia em que se faz referência a um órgão ou entidade metafísica (espírito, alma, etc.) como o local de origem e/ou manifestação de algo.

Comment: *Sede*, que tu mesmo usas para traduzir *seat*, não serve? Ou procuras palavras que já tenham sido usadas?

Comment: Sim, de preferência algo já em uso. Eu não encontrei expressões em português que já tenham sido usadas nesse sentido. Mas "sede" me parece uma tradução um tanto forçada. Por enquanto estou usando "origem" ou "berço". Pelo que o Google me mostrou, as expressões "seat of ..." são termos técnicos bastante usados em contextos religiosos na língua inglesa; mas encontrei também alguns usos em dicionários e textos que falam desses elementos noutras culturas não-bíblicas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar ***sede*** ou ***centro***. Ambas as palavras estão em uso e aparecem nalguns dicionários com o sentido pretendido. Cito o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002, desenvolvendo as abreviações):

> **sede** *s.f.* (1446 cf. OrdAF) **1** lugar em que alguém se pode sentar; assento, cadeira […] **10** *por metáfora* ponto de concentração de certos factos ou fenómenos fisiológicos **11** *por metáfora* centro de ação, de irradiação de um poder, de uma faculdade <*o cérebro é a sede do pensamento*>
>
> **centro** […] **7** *por metáfora, formal* área abstrata sensorial ou psíquica <*centro do prazer*> <*centro das emoções*>

Estas palavras têm sido usadas neste sentido no contexto quer de crenças antigas quer da neurologia moderna. E já há algum tempo. Eis alguns exemplos, começando com *sede* (negrito meu):

> Será o coração ou os intestinos **a sede das emoções** como o medo, o ódio?
>   [*Receitas Mágicas*, 1973.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=mgNZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sede%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&dq=%22sede%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1vNy3nInXAhWG6oMKHWa0DyIQ6AEI7wEwGw)
>
> […] a importância fundamental do **hipotálamo** que, sendo ou não a verdadeira **sede das emoções**, desempenha incontrovertidamente no mecanismo das mesmas, uma função de primeira ordem.
>   [*Neurobiologia*, vol. 15, 1952.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=OxthAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sede%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&dq=%22sede%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1vNy3nInXAhWG6oMKHWa0DyIQ6AEI9QEwHA)
>
> Este tipo de abordagem puramente especulativa hoje em dia só pode ser equiparada ao temos daqueles que, no século XVII, recusavam-se a estudar o funcionamento do **coração** para continuar sustentando que nele está **a sede das emoções e sentimentos**.
>   [João de Fernandes Teixeira, *Mentes e máquinas*, 1998.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=FHnAXY5fHqoC&pg=PA151&dq=%22recusavam-se%20a%20estudar%20o%20funcionamento%20do%20cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20para%20continuar%20sustentando%20que%20nele%20est%C3%A1%20a%20sede%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20e%20sentimentos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmuL_Nn4nXAhWBrxQKHUzkDggQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22recusavam-se%20a%20estudar%20o%20funcionamento%20do%20cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20para%20continuar%20sustentando%20que%20nele%20est%C3%A1%20a%20sede%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20e%20sentimentos%22&f=false)

E agora uns com *centro*

> Até ao século XVII, os nossos antecessores médicos supunham que **o coração era o centro das emoções** e que era com o coração que amávamos ou sentíamos prazer.
>   [*Notícias da África do Sul*, 1968.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=f_kwAQAAIAAJ&q=%22o%20cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20era%20o%20centro%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&dq=%22o%20cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20era%20o%20centro%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiToeCL6onXAhUMp5QKHQbHAEEQ6AEINTAC)
>
> “O tálamo — diz Chauchard (1947) — é o centro da dôr porque é o **centro das emoções, a séde dos reflexos emotivos**, da efetividade elementar inconsciente”
>   [*Revista do Hospital N. Senhora Aparecida*, vol. 4, 1951.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=BNQ0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22centro%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&dq=%22centro%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmz_3b54nXAhUEI5AKHeN0DIwQ6AEIygEwGA)
>
> CHAKRA DO PLEXO SOLAR — Localiza-se na altura do estômago. No corpo físico, rege as funções digestivas, o estômago, o fígado e os intestinos. **É o centro das emoções** e faz parte do processamento mental das impressões, sensações e reações aos estímulos externos e internos.
>   [Marilu Martinelli, *Conversando sobre educação em valores humanos*, 1999.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YnCrkwne-vAC&pg=PA71&dq=%22centro%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF1-_c6onXAhWCVrwKHR13CIMQ6AEIiQEwDg#v=onepage&q=%22centro%20das%20emo%C3%A7%C3%B5es%22&f=false)